# How would flight factor into shepherding for Aarakocra (birdfolk, basically)?

Tags: science-based, winged-humans, livestock

So, my setting, as of now, is a singular supercontinent, with a large mountain system running across one of its sides, basically the fantasy equivalent of the Andes.
On paper this (or at least its ocean-facing side) is the home of the Aarakocra (aka: bird people with a stupid name).

They have sophisticated but small-size agriculture and live in isolated villages. As far as plant cultivation goes, I just copy-paste that from the Inca Empire, but animal husbandry is affected by two important things:

Shepherds can fly, more precisely soar, and have the eyesight of a golden eagle. These two attributes massively impact herding practices for them, **so how would their practices differ from the human ones in similar terrain?**

Aarakocra are humanoid creatures, covered with feathers. They have six limbs, two of which are the wings. Their flight capabilities are similar to large birds, like the *Argentavis Magnificens*. Aka: limited take off frequency and good gliding capabilities.

Comment: How do you want it to? You're designed the creature, and it's capabilities.

Comment: @Ash Do you need more info, or suggest that it's all up to my discretion (it isn't)?

Comment: The latter because it actually is.

Comment: Even if you're using a race you didn't create and are stuck with a completely immutable set of attributes it's up to you how much, and it what ways, those abilities are allowed to effect the story you'r telling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Shepherds can fly, more precisely soar, and have the eyesight of a golden eagle. These two attributes massively impact herding practices for them, so how would their practices differ from the human ones in similar terrain?

Shepherds who could have exceedingly good vision, tracking abilities and could fly? If only there were modern, technologically assisted human sheperds who you could use for inspiration here...

[image: Helicopter mustering]
(image from [Mt Hutt helicopters](https://www.mthutthelicopters.com/mustering))

Turns out that helicopters are widely used for livestock management on very large, or quite mountainous terrain in places like the US, Australia and NZ for a range of species include sheep, cows, deer and horses. Either directly, by flying the helicopter around the herd to drive them, or indirectly, by lifting sheperds up to areas that are a long and difficult journey on foot but trivial by air. Plenty more pictures, videoes, documentaries and news articles for you to read out there.

Here's one to get you started: ["Bulldoggers" in wild and wooly roundup](https://www.pressreader.com/new-zealand/the-press/20090113/281487862226798)

---

So, helicopters aren't like eagles, but the basic principles are still there, and the major advantages are largely there too. Namely: you can have your herds spread over a pretty big area. If you're fit and manoeuvrable you can drive them without setting foot on the ground, though depending on the aerobatic capabilities of your peeps this may not be practical unless your herd species behave reliably and usefully under those circumstances. If you're strong enough, you can carry work animals up with you (do your birdpeeps domesticate dogs? They'd still be useful) and carry livestock back down again (to retrieve missing, sick or otherwise injured animals). Even if you're not strong enough, it may be practical to use carry nets to share the load between multiple flyers, if they're trained and practised in such aerial coordination.

Your "ranch" can cover some quite unreasonable terrain... very mountainous, for goats and sheep, or very wet, for things like water buffalo. You don't need to live in that unreasonable terrain during the season (unlike traditional mountain shepherds) because you can easily travel up to the high pastures or out to the swamps most days, so the issues of feeding and housing and survival of shepherds are much reduced. Finding straying or missing livestock will be much easier with a raptor's eye than with a human equivalent.

Some herd species won't even need physical boundaries, as you can replicate the human technique of [hefting](http://sciencesearch.defra.gov.uk/Default.aspx?Menu=Menu&Module=More&Location=None&Completed=0&ProjectID=15631) to train your flock to stick to your mountainside, so there's no need to go flying up mountains and spend all day building walls.

Answer (score 4):

Starfish Prime's answer is very good, but there are a couple elements to the analogy that wouldn't be present in your circumstance.  While SP is aware it's an imperfect analogy, I want to directly address these differences.

1. If you use something like a helicopter, you probably only have one of them.  Very large operations might have two or three, but, still, use will be limited.  If you have an entire race of beings who fly, you have many chances to lay eyes on your flocks from the air.
2. Helicopters and other large equipment must be operated by adults (perhaps a very skilled teen) who have extensive training.

**In real life, [shepherds are often children](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shepherd).**  Depending of course on the amount of work involved and how long they needed to be away from the village in order to do their work.

> In many societies, shepherds were an important part of the economy.
>   Unlike farmers, shepherds were often wage earners, being paid to watch
>   the sheep of others. Shepherds also lived apart from society, being
>   largely nomadic. It was mainly a job of solitary males without
>   children, and new shepherds thus needed to be recruited externally.
>   Shepherds were most often the younger sons of farming peasants who did
>   not inherit any land. In other societies, each family would have a
>   family member to shepherd its flock, often a child, youth or an elder
>   who couldn't help much with harder work; these shepherds were fully
>   integrated in society.
>
> Shepherds would normally work in groups either looking after one large
>   flock, or each bringing their own and merging their responsibilities.
>   They would live in small cabins, often shared with their sheep, and
>   would buy food from local communities. Less often shepherds lived in
>   covered wagons that traveled with their flocks.

Children would be more likely to do the work in situations where they could go home at night and where there wasn't as much physical danger (from being trampled or from fighting off predators, for example).

If your people can fly, a society is much more likely to send a child to go check on things, then come back to get help if required.  A child (or a small group of them) could also hang out with the livestock all day and fly home each night.  In the case of danger, the children would fly into the air to escape it (if they ever come down at all).

They can also alert other adults to help more easily than land-bound shepherds because of their eyesight.  Not only is it much better that that of humans, but being in the air gives them advantages as well.  One because they will see problems from further away, which gives them more time to get help and also they'll (sometimes) be closer to home when they see it.  One because adults are more likely to spot them from afar as they fly home in distress.

In larger communities, or ones with many widespread herds, you could have a group of flyers whose sole job it is to be communication beacons (assuming of course that you don't have modern technology).

Adults would do the heavy work, like moving herds.  In many cases, they might join the children to help direct something like a change of pastures.

This means more adults in your society are free to do other work (either full or part time).  It also means there's more work for children than there might be otherwise, so your educational systems will change to accommodate that.  School can be in the pastures (or on a hill overlooking one), or during times when the herds are closer to home (just after mass birthings or when the grass isn't available.  If your society doesn't have formal academics, then "school" times would be when the children are trained in other adult occupations.

Answer (score 2):

The bulk of time spent herding is actually spent *not* herding. That is, it's spent being available to solve some problem as it arises. The wolves (or whatever) show up and must be dealt with according to local regulations. There is a grass fire. Some sheep (or whatever) gets caught in some situation it can't get out of. Somebody trespasses or tries to steal your sheep.

Outside these times you want to be available someplace nearby in such a way that you can conserve energy, not pay much attention, but be alert for whatever signals.  You hear sheep making racket. Or your sheepdog making racket. Or you smell smoke.

Unless you are an exceptionally energy efficient flyer, probably you would go sit on a hill under a shade tree and sleep. Or read a book. Or whatever way you pass the time when there's not much to do. These days probably hand-held solar-charged electronics.

Being able to fly might get you to the problem faster. It will depend how much weight one of these folk can carry while flying. Can an injured sheep be flown to the vet? Can the vet fly while carrying his gear?  Being able to fly might make hunting the wolves easier. It might make finding the injured-sheep-in-a-ditch easier. It might make spotting the grass fire easier.

A few times per year there is some activity that requires heavy work. Shearing time, vaccination time, tagging/branding time, etc. These won't be much affected by being able to fly. Maybe you fly the branding gear in. Probably you don't fly the commercial product out, whatever it might be. Milk or wool or fresh lamb chops you probably use some conventional vehicle. I don't feature winged guys flying along carrying 20 gallon cans of milk.

So, overall, probably flying is mostly a convenience going-and-coming. The actual work of herding probably won't be affected much by flying. It's all down to sitting and watching sheep eat grass.

Comment: oddly enough there is [actually an answer on how much they can carry](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/76758/how-much-weight-can-an-aarakocra-carry-when-flying) but the answer itself acknowledges that is is not realistic (they only weigh about 80-100 lbs themselves)